# spark sql : GC overhead limit exceeded when reading parquet partitioned files

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying read existing parquet files from hdfs using spark sql for my POC, but hitting the OOM error.

I need to read all the portioned files, for a given partition date. The partition is as follows : date/file_dir_id

1. There are 1200 sub folders under date folder
2. There are in total 234769 .parquet files under all these folders(Not a huge number)
3. Overall size of all the .parquet files is 10g

Parquet folder structure

1. Date

   - File_dir_1

     - File_1.parquet
     - File_2.parquet
   - File_dir_2

     - File_3.parquet
     - File_3.parquet

When I try to read the files for a particular date, numbers as mentioned above
sparkSession.read().schema(someSchema).parquet(hdfs_path_folder/date=2018-03-05/*); // I get the below mentioned error.

Other details

1. Running in yarn / cluster mode
2. Spark 2.3
3. 4 Node cluster(32 core/128 gb)
4. 5 Executors / 4 cores each

**It doesn't help if I increase the driver memory or executor memory. Any help on how to overcome this please ?**

### Error Details

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.appendSchemeSpecificPart(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.toString(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles$3$$anonfun$7.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:235)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles$3$$anonfun$7.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:228)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foreach(ArraySeq.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles$3.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles$3.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:227)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:227)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles$1.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$InMemoryFileIndex$$bulkListLeafFiles$1.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:171)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
```

Comment: Running into this too; Driver seems to have plenty of memory and GC logs look normal. Not sure what's going on?

Comment: have you resolve this issue?, facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

When spark try to read from parquet, internally it will try to build a
[InMemoryFileIndex](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/InMemoryFileIndex.html)

In the spark job, we will see a job like

```
Listing leaf files and directories for 1200 paths:
```

This issue is because the number of paths to scan is too large

Increase driver memory and core solve the issue for me

```
 'driver.cores': 4,
 'driver.memory': '8g'
```